# Anisotropic vs Isotropic Material Mass Density

Tags: material-science

Since anisotropic materials are direction dependent in X,Y, Z axis compared to isotropic materials, can we say oftenly anisotropic materials have less mass density than isotropic ones?

Thanks in advance
KR

Comment: It has to do more with homogeneity rather than isotropism. And not, it might be even true but your assertion is not a consequence.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks, I understand that  less mass is not a consequence of dependent/or independent of direction. What if I say like that, assume an anisotropic material which has one high dielectric constant in X direction, assume it's 30 and other axis (y and z) is 1, and Isotropic material has a dielectric constant value of 30 in all directions. Isn't that lots of atomic particles involved in isotropic rather than anisotropic? So the anisotropic material will have less mass density. This's just what I think. I'd like to hear your comment, is that what you meant? I'm asking to verify

Comment: Yes if you fix say elemental composition that some parts will have less some more density. However note that anisotropy does not point to different density even. At least not until one goes to molecular level. For instance take graphite. It is highly anisotropic, but homogenous at least until one reach interlayer distance or so....